# Can you serialize using a interface collection with interface entries?

Tags: java

Suppose I have

```
public interface General extends Serializable {
   ...
}
```

and

```
public class Specific implements General {
   ...
}
```

Can I send and object of the type `ArrayList<Specific>` through an `ObjectOutputStream` and deserialize it by casting to `List<General>`? Will that work? If not, how should I do it?

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Comment: What a specific error you have?

Answer (score 0):

I havent tried it myself , but I think it will work - take a look at `ArrayList.readObject()/writeObject()`. The `writeObject()` will write the `Specific` objects , and the `readObject()` should be able to read them back as instances of `Specific` , and each element in the deserialized list is a `General` reference so that should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

ArrayList is Serializable, per the javadocs (many of the Collection classes are, so long as the object they contain is), so long as the generic type is serializable, the serialization side works - you'd serialize and read back an object that is an ArrayList

That's an iffy cast.  In general, it would be considered unsafe. If you had a

```
 List<Specific>
```

you would not be able to cast it to

```
 List<Generic>
```

They are not the same thing logically (even if they really are, at runtime).   In fact, a direct cast like that in a program would be problematic, because then this is valid:

```
List<Specific> specific = ...;
List<Generic> generic = (List<Generic>) specific;

generic.add(new OtherImplExtendingGeneric());
specific.get(specific.length() -1).methodOnlyOnSpecific(); // Kersplode
```

But you are treating it as an Object, and you have no other reference to the other type, so it will work out.  It won't prevent you from doing it.  It will technically produce the desired outcome.   There might be reason for it, but it would certainly make me raise an eyebrow in the code review.

Why do you need to cast the generic type?

Comment: So, I just had this log manager that manages logs from many clients. All logs have start and ends time, regardless of whatever they're logging. I just do something like `log.discardWhatsBefore(maximumLogStartTime)` for all logs, which may completely different, but all contain a method called `getStart()` and `getEndTime()`. The idea is get only the intersection of all logs.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it works:

```
out.writeObject(list);
```

and

```
List<General> list = (List<General>)in.readObject();
```

The difference between types in generics and "normal" data types is that generics are only visible to the compiler, not at runtime. That means that a cast with generics is not 100 % safe because at runtime `List<A>` and `List<B>` are the same.

But if you are sure that the list is a list of `General` I see no problem here.

Comment: Great, so as long as I know that the `List` of `General` is, for sure, an `ArrayList` of `Specific`, it'll work. Cool!